# Kubens command fails due to unable to open certificate due to permission denial

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, permission-denied

I get the error below when I run 'kubens'

```
error: could not list namespaces (is the cluster accessible?): failed to initialize k8s REST client: failed to initialize config: invalid configuration: [unable to read client-cert (~path)/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt for minikube due to open (~path)/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt: permission denied, unable to read client-key (~path)/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key for minikube due to open (~path)/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key: permission denied, unable to read certificate-authority (~path)/.minikube/ca.crt for minikube due to open (~path)/.minikube/ca.crt: permission denied]
```

Comment: Have you tried with sudo?

Comment: Check permissions for this files.

Comment: @euTIMER permission is me. yes, didn't work with sudo